# Passing State to axios post request body gives Error 422 in React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, axios

I am trying to execute a code using judge0 API but when I use state variables I get an Error. But when I provide plain text as a request data then the API call is executed fine.

Given is the component's code :

```
const IDE = () => {

    const ids = {
        'python': 71,
        'java': 62,
        'cpp':54
    }
    const langs = {
        'python': '#Your Code goes here!',
        'java': `class HelloWorld {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        //  Your code goes here!
     }
 }`,
    'cpp':`#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    // Your Code goes here!
    return 0;
}`
    }

    const [code, setCode] = useState("#Your Code Goes HERE!");
    const [lang, setLang] = useState('python');
    const [id, setId] = useState(71);
    useEffect(() => { 
        setCode(langs[lang])
    }, [lang]);

    useEffect(() => { 
        setId(ids[lang])
    }, [lang]);

    const onChange = React.useCallback((code) => {
        setCode(code);
    }, []);



    async function SubmitCode() {
        console.log(code, id)
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://judge0-ce.p.rapidapi.com/submissions',
            params: {
                fields: '*'
            },
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-RapidAPI-Key': '****',
                'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'judge0-ce.p.rapidapi.com'
            },
            data: {
                language_id: {id},
                source_code: `${code}`,
            }
        };

        try {
            let response = await axios.request(options);
            const token = response.data.token;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
```

The above code shows this error:
[image]

But when I replace the state Variables by plain text, I get it done. For eg:

```
data: {
                language_id: 71,
                source_code: `print("Hello World!")`,
            }
```

I get the response correct.
[image]

What should I do to resolve it?